# How to display dictionary with dataframes on a localhost (using Flask and Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary, flask

I have the following dict:

```
{'id': 1, 'df': pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'col1': ['kuku', 'dudu', 'lulu'], 'col2': [8,9,10]}), 'df_size': 3}
```

When I am trying to print it using Flask app on my `localhost:5000` it returns an error:

```
@app.route("/showDict")
def show_dict():
    import pandas as pd
    return {'id': 1, 'df': pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'col1': ['kuku', 'dudu', 'lulu'], 'col2': [8,9,10]}), 'df_size': 3}
```

> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} ' TypeError:
> Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

Please advise how can I print such a dict via Flask app?

Answer (score 1):

You should convert your dict to json before you return it, try this:

```
@app.route("/showDict")
def show_dict():
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'col1': ['kuku', 'dudu', 'lulu'], 'col2': [8, 9, 10]}).to_json()
    return {'id': 1, 'df': df, 'df_size': 3}
```

you can see this article, I hope this can help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dumps-in-python/

Comment: It doesn't work: TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable

Comment: @SteveS I'm sorry for that there is a problem with previous answer. I changed the code and tested in my computer, and it's work.